# Calculations with Landsat datasets in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I'm looking to transform my Landsat data-sets to correct for differences in sensors between missions

The mathematical function I am hoping to apply is-

```
NDVIL8 = 0.0235 + 0.9723 * NDVIL5,7
```

But I am not sure how to achieve this in earth engine

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need is something like this:

```js
var randomImage = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA").first();

var newImage = randomImage.multiply(0.9723).add(0.0235);
print(newImage);
```